# generating random numbers based on the comments array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am having issues when writing this code, and I think i botched the whole thing.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Here is what I have so far

```
public class FArray {
    // build an array of 10 numbers of random numbers, and then display them out
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare an array (named numbs) that holds 10 ints
        int[] numbs = new int[10];
        // write a for loop that loops 10 times and generates a random number between 0 and 100
        for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
            numbs[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);

            // assign the random number to each element in the array , numbs
            numbs = new numbers();
            // write a for loop that displays to the screen each random number in the array named numbs
            numbers[i] = Numbers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what `numbs = new numbers();` is supposed to mean?

Comment: Looks like you were supposed to write 2 `for` loops but you only wrote 1.

Comment: I am very new to these arrays and dont understand it much. I looked it up on the internet and it said to designate numbs to numbers like that.

Comment: @ryan What are you trying to do with the following statements? `numbs = new numbers();`  and `numbers[i] = Numbers;`

Comment: to be honest, no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print 10 number randomely you can do this using a stream of integer, in this stream we iterate from 0 to 10 and for each of the integer we print a random double between 0 and 100 :

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> System.out.println(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
```

Edit : if you only want to insert 10 random values into your array numbs and after that printing them you only have to remove this two lines :

```
        numbs = new numbers();
        // write a for loop that displays to the screen each random number in the array named numbs
        numbers[i] = Numbers;
```

So your main method will look like this :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare an array (named numbs) that holds 10 ints
    int[] numbs = new int[10];
    // write a for loop that loops 10 times and generates a random number between 0 and 100
    for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
       numbs[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    }
    // print the values
    for (int number : numbs) {
       System.out.println(number);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I do not completely understand how that would fit into an array. even thought it might be easier to do i am learning in my book how to do arrays.

Comment: thank you that helped alot. it makes more sense now.